# Am i using eval() safely in server?

Tags: javascript, express, security, eval, server-side

To put it shortly, i am using the **eval** to dynamically call functions (that all have same name in front and the last bit differs) that i use for validating a client's cookies.

```js
const cookie_names = ['cookiename_1', 'cookiename_2'];

exports.validateCookies = (req, res, next) => {
    const cookie_types = filterUnknownCookies(Object.keys(req.cookies));
    for(let cookie of cookie_types){
        res.locals[cookie] = eval(`validateCookie${cookie}('${req.cookies[cookie]}')`);
    }
    next();
}

const filterUnknownCookies = (cookie_arr) => {
    cookie_arr = cookie_arr.filter(name =>  cookie_names.findIndex( validnames => validnames === name) + 1);

    return cookie_arr;
}
```

Since i knew that using the eval function might be dangerous, i hardcoded the valid cookie names and filtered anything that didn't match them in the array.
So the question: is filtering the array from any unwanted strings (names) safe enough to counter the eval's exploitability?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Depends whether users can create cookies or not.

Comment: Please share your website URL =))

Comment: @M-Chen-3 - Any malicious user can create any cookie they want and attach it to a request coming into your server.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yikes. That's good to know. This is the first time I've ever been scared of cookies.

Comment: @Kosh so my website is : DoYouUseStackOverflow.ToAttackOthers.huh go ahead and give it a try(●'◡'●)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So the question: is filtering the array from any unwanted strings (names) safe enough to counter the eval's exploitability?

No.  This is not safe. In fact, it does basically nothing to safeguard you because the cookie names you allow are still completely unguarded and unsanitized.  What you have is potentially unsafe because a malicious client can put anything they want in that cookie and you're "hoping" that they can't find something that will break out of the string delimiter you have.  But, it is possible to break out of that string delimiter by just terminating the string and then adding a function call.  This would potentially allow an attacker to execute arbitrary code on your server.

The ONLY thing you should ever use `eval()` with is a trusted string from your own server-side code or a completely sanitized string form the outside.  But, nearly always, you don't need `eval()` as there is another and safer way to code it.

Here, you don't need to use `eval()` at all.  You can just create a lookup table for the legal functions to call and then pass the function directly to it:

```
try {
    res.locals[cookie] = validateCookie[cookie](req.cookies[cookie]);
} catch(e) {
    // either invalid cookie or exception in the function
    // handle that here
}
```

And, of course, your `validateCookie[cookie]()` function also has to be coded defensively to know that it may be passed anything.  You don't show us the code for that function to be able to comment on it further.

In this case, `validateCookie` is a lookup table that contains the valid `cookie` names and their corresponding functions:

```
 // cookie processing lookup table
 const validateCookie = {
      cookieName1: validateCookieName1,
      cookieName2: validateCookieName2
 };
```

Lookup tables like this are often how you avoid trying to manufacture a function name and a string and use `eval()` to call it.  This also adds the safety feature that this code can't call any function that is not in your lookup table.

Comment: Unrelated, but is it safe for me to use `eval` in my CS50 Calculator where I control what users can type? Link to that is in my profile.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 - I didn't study your code, but anything coming from the client is insecure.  It can be spoofed or controlled by any malicious attacker.  You may control what is typed in your web page, but you don't control what some attacker puts in a manufactured request to your server.  So, using `eval()` on an arbitrary string coming from your client is NOT safe.  We'd have to see your server code and where/what you're using `eval()` for to comment further.  This should be in a new question, not piggybacked on this one.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll ask a new question.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks a lot for your help and insight I completely misjudged the amount of spoofing that the web can provide... Although the validationCookie functions only take a string as a parameter that is then checked with a local db of cookies that i have made, i am pretty sure the answer you provided is actually 10x simpler and safer.

Answer (score 1):

No the code is not safe, not because it doesn't sanitize the name of the validation method, but because it evaluates uploaded text as JavaScript when expanding the string template literal:

```
 `... ${req.cookies[cookie]} ...`
```

I just tested and injected code using a carefully crafted string value for `req.cookies[cookie]`, which I will refrain from publishing here.

It may be slightly safer to evaluate the validation call without expanding the data string, as in

```
`validateCookie${cookie}` + "(req.cookies[cookie])"
```

which would pass uploaded text to the validation routine without evaluation as code, but the safety of avoiding `eval` altogether remains the same. Avoiding `eval` can easily be achieved by using a lookup table of validation function object values keyed by function name.